# asyncio monitor coroutine status

Tags: python, multithreading, python-asyncio, python-multithreading

I have an advanced case where there is a great need to monitor thread status.

I'm using a graphql library and trying to consolidate calls to the server, however that is just my use case.  This same problem should apply in any situation where:

> 1. You must determine what calls to make
> 2. Pause resolution of the data awaiting those calls
> 3. Consolidate the calls to make.
> 4. Make the calls.
> 5. Resume the original resolution of the data with the result of those calls.
> 6. Don't block the main thread.

This is something that keeps coming up due to the proliferation of `asyncio` across many libraries.  Here is a simplification of the strategy I find myself trying:

```py
# %%

import uuid
import asyncio
import random

_ids = {}

# process all the _id values at one time, after they have 
# been gathered.
async def do_something_with_ids(_ids):
    
    #print to show _ids are not gathered yet
    print(f'_IDS-0: {_ids}')
    
    # 'magic' sleep to wait for _ids to be gathered.
    # (cannot be in final build)
    await asyncio.sleep(3)
    
    # do actual processing
    _ids.update({k:bool(random.getrandbits(1)) for k in _ids.keys()})
    
    return _ids

async def async_test(_ids, t_process):
    
    # create id and add it to _ids
    _uuid = uuid.uuid4()
    _ids[_uuid] = None
    
    # wait for processing to finish
    await t_process
    
    #return value to original caller
    return _ids[_uuid]


t_process = asyncio.create_task(do_something_with_ids(_ids))

t1 = asyncio.create_task(async_test(_ids, t_process))
t2 = asyncio.create_task(async_test(_ids, t_process))
t3 = asyncio.create_task(async_test(_ids, t_process))
t4 = asyncio.create_task(async_test(_ids, t_process))

# Need something here to tell me that all my t{x} tasks
# have reached their awaits.
# .... ? what code to use?

# await processing
await t_process

# retrieve values
result = [await v for v in (t1, t2, t3, t4)]


display(
    result, 
)
```

NOTE: this is from an interactive python file in VSCode.  If you want to run it somewhere else you need to wrap the final two await calls in an async function and create a loop to call it.

The gist is Task `do_something_with_ids` can't begin till all `async_test` tasks have awaited.  However, `async_test` can't resolve till `do_something_with_ids` is finished.

My example is just a simplification, but in production it needs to be assumed that within either function there are other coroutines going on.  So within `do_something_with_ids` and `async_test` any number of functions could be resolved in any order, but `do_something_with_ids` and `async_test` over all, need to await in this order:

```
async_test
do_something_with_ids
async_test
```

Is there a way to inspect a task and determine if it is blocked?

**EDIT 1** -----------------------------------

Based on feed back from @PaulCornelius, I tried a new derivation of the algorithm.

```py
import uuid
import asyncio
import random
import time

_ids = {}

async def do_something_with_ids(_ids):
    print(f'_IDS-0: {_ids}')
    await asyncio.sleep(3)
    _ids.update({k:bool(random.getrandbits(1)) for k in _ids.keys()})
    return _ids

async def async_test(_ids, t_process):
    _uuid = uuid.uuid4()
    _ids[_uuid] = None

    #t_process is actually a Future here
    await t_process
    return _ids[_uuid]

#Set up future to use as a call back.
future = asyncio.Future()

t1 = asyncio.create_task(async_test(_ids, future))
t2 = asyncio.create_task(async_test(_ids, future))
t3 = asyncio.create_task(async_test(_ids, future))
t4 = asyncio.create_task(async_test(_ids, future))

await do_something_with_ids(_ids)
future.set_result(0)
result = [await v for v in (t1, t2, t3, t4)]

display(
    result, 
)
```

The results of this are:

```
_IDS-0: {}
[False, False, False, False]
```

So, scheduled task don't seem to be attempted until the main thread hits the first await:

```py
await do_something_with_ids(_ids)
```

Is there a way to await until blocked?  If we could do that we could await the t{x} tasks until blocked and create a solution here.

Comment: The simple short answer to your question is that there is no sense to a function that determines if a Task is blocked.  For any event loop, there is exactly one running Task at any given moment; therefore all other Tasks must be blocked.  That doesn't help you, of course.  The usual way to handle this situation is with synchronization primitives, perhaps some asyncio.Event objects.  In your comment you say that a timed wait cannot be in the final code (a good principle) - well, what CAN be?

Comment: I also see that your program has all 7 tasks (main, do_something, plus 4 async_tests) awaiting on one another in a complex web of inter-dependencies.  That says to me that somehow there must be a better design to start with.  I get that you're trying to come up with a simplified example for an SO post, but can you think of a refactoring that would reduce the coupling between tasks?

Comment: @PaulCornelius - 1. Interdependency web refactor:  A refactor would be the ideal solution, if I maintained ownership of all code in the  pipeline.  However, in reality I'm using other libraries (graphene, graphql-core-3), where my `async_test` function is passed to the graph schema, and they handle awaiting the resulting coroutine.  So all I can refactor is the code __inside__ `async_test`.  In actuality, this problem keeps cropping up.  It seems the ubiquitous asyncio becomes with python libraries, the more I encounter this scenario.

Comment: 2. `For any event loop, there is exactly one running Task at any given moment; therefore all other Tasks must be blocked,` this gives me an idea.  Maybe I'm over engineering in my brain.  The golden rule of async, is generally __YOU HAVE NO IDEA WHAT YOUR PROCESSORS DOING__  Perhaps, in this case I do though.  When I create a task `t1 = asyncio.create_task(myTask())`, can I depend on that task being fully awaited by the time execution hits the next line?

Comment: No, you can actually depend on the opposite.  The task will not even be started by the time your code hits the next line - it will be "pending."  You misstate the golden rule of asyncio: in fact, you know what the processor is doing because TASK SWITCHES CAN OCCUR ONLY AT AWAIT EXPRESSIONS.   Prime directive: No await, no task switch.  It's "cooperative multitasking."  This is as opposed to threading, where the CPU can switch threads at any line of code.  Thread switches are under control of the OS, not your code.

Comment: Change your statement to `t1 = await asyncio.create_task(myTask())` and now you can say that by the next line of code, the task will be not only started but FINISHED.  That's because `await t`, where t is some task, means in effect: "wait for t to finish."  Conceptually asyncio is actually fairly simple, but far from easy to use effectively in practice.  And the documentation is missing a good presentation of the basic guidelines.  You have asked some good questions here.  I recommend looking through the section on synchronization primitives.

Comment: @PaulCornelius - if you try to `t1 = await asyncio.create_task(myTask())` you'll lock the main thread.  It depends on the `Future` which will never be reachable.

Comment: You DO NOT lock the main thread.  You lock the Task where the await expression appears, and another Task in the same thread now assumes control.  Your program as you presented it is not multithreading.  Asyncio is cooperative multitasking in a single thread.

Comment: @PaulCornelius - it definitely locks the main thread.  You can paste the code as is and try it.